# Perl typeglobs and Real References: What do I gain if I write to \*STDOUT instead of *STDOUT?

Tags: perl

What do I gain if I write to a real reference like `\*STDOUT` instead of a typeglob like `*STDOUT`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One is a [typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles), another is a reference to it.

As far as I know, the main practical difference is that you **can NOT bless a typeglob into an object, but you CAN bless the typeglob reference** (which is what `IO::Handle` does)

This distinction is discussed in detail in "Perl Cookbook", Recipe 7.16. "Storing Filehandles in Variable".

---

Another difference is that assigning a glob creates an alias to the ENTIRE glob, whereas assigning a glob reference does the expected (as discussed in [`perldoc perlmod, "Symbol Tables" section`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables). To illustrate:

```
@STDOUT=(5);
$globcopy1 = *STDOUT; # globcopy1 is aliased to the entire STDOUT glob, 
                      # including alias to array @STDOUT
$globcopy2 = \*STDOUT; # globcopy2 merely stores a reference to a glob, 
                       # and doesn't have anything to do with @STDOUT

print $globcopy1 "TEST print to globcopy1/STDOUT as filehandle\n";
print "TEST print of globcopy1/STDOUT as array: $globcopy1->[0]\n\n";
print $globcopy2 "TEST print to globcopy2/STDOUT as filehandle\n";
print "TEST print of globcopy2/STDOUT as array: $globcopy2->[0]\n\n";
```

Produces:

```
TEST print to globcopy1/STDOUT as filehandle
TEST print of globcopy1/STDOUT as array: 5

TEST print to globcopy2/STDOUT as filehandle
Not an ARRAY reference at line 8.
```

---

As a side note, a rumor that the typeglob reference is the only way to pass the filehandle into a function is not the case:

```
sub pfh { my $fh = $_[0]; print $fh $_[1]; }

pfh(*STDOUT, "t1\n");
pfh(\*STDOUT, "t2\n");

# Output:
# t1
# t2
```

Comment: There's also a great axample of this in "Object Oriented Perl" by Damian Conway on page 158ff.

Answer (score 4):

`*` indicates a typeglob, which is an entry in the symbol table.  Eg:

```
my $x;
print *x;
```

Will yield `*main::x`.

`\` indicates a reference.  Try this:

```
use YAML::XS;

print Dump *STDOUT;
print Dump \*STDOUT;
```

The first one is a glob, the second is a reference.  Presumably when you do this:

```
my $fh = *STDOUT;
```

You're actually copying the glob into a new entry, although I do not think this is very meaningful -- if you now `close STDOUT`, `$fh` is closed too.  This:

```
my $fh = \*STDOUT;
```

is just a reference, and that's what's preferred.  See also:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles

Comment: +1 for showing the results of dumping the glob and its reference.

Comment: You can also get to the different slots of the typeglob by first dereferencing the typeglob and then adding the sign of the type we want. If we e.g. want what is stored in `$STDOUT` we could now say `${*$fh}` which looks weird, but works. We need the curlies because otherwise perl would think we mean `$*` and `$fh`.

Answer (score 3):

You get a reference to the typeglob named `STDOUT`. See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Here's what it says on this:

> It isn't possible to create a true reference to an IO handle
>   (filehandle or dirhandle) using the backslash operator. The most you
>   can get is a reference to a typeglob, which is actually a complete
>   symbol table entry. But see the explanation of the *foo{THING} syntax
>   below. However, you can still use type globs and globrefs as though
>   they were IO handles.

[perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) is also helpful.

In conclusion, it's like building a reference to a filehandle. You can use it as one. But with the typeglob, you can do other things as well. The symbol table holds the values of all variables named `STDOUT`, that is `$STDOUT`, `@STDOUT`, `%STDOUT` and even`&STDOUT`, as well as the filehandle. You can access them all with just the one typeglob. But In case of `STDOUT` you probably don't have to worry about it because you will not likely have a `%STDOUT` in your code.

This kind of reference also is the only way to pass a filehandle as an argument to a function.

```
sub myprint {
  my $fh = shift;
  print $fh "Hello World!\n";
}
&myprint(\*STDOUT);
```

Comment: It's good information, but it doesn't actually answer the question of what you gain from using a reference instead of a glob

Comment: sorry, that last one is not really true. Did you try `&myprint(*STDOUT);` ?  Also, see the example in my answer.

Comment: Correct, but how's \STDOUT related to the original question?

Answer (score 2):

Perl provides 3 ways to get the same filehandle:

- `*STDOUT` is a [typeglob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2244156/3614563)
- `\*STDOUT` is a reference to a typeglob
- `*STDOUT{IO}` is either undef or a reference to an IO::Handle

I now prefer to use `\*STDOUT` for consistency. When I use `open(my $handle, ...)` to autovivify a filehandle, Perl gives me a reference to a typeglob. So if I want to use either `STDOUT` or an open file, I might write

```
my $handle;
if ($path eq "-") {
    $handle = \*STDOUT;
} else {
    open($handle, '>', $path) or die "Can't open $path: $!";
}
```

so my handle is always a reference to a typeglob. This consistency isn't too important. The rest of my code shouldn't care whether it has a reference to a typeglob, or some other kind of filehandle.

Given my preference for `\*FH`, I am surprised to find an example where `*FH` works but `\*FH` fails. In [perlsub, "Pass by Reference"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Pass-by-Reference), I find this example:

> If you're planning on generating new filehandles, you could do this. Notice to pass back just the bare *FH, not its reference.
>
> ```
> sub openit {
>     my $path = shift;
>     local *FH;
>     return open (FH, $path) ? *FH : undef;
> }
> ```

It really needs to pass back `*FH`, not `\*FH`, though perlsub doesn't explain why. I verified it myself by calling the sub in a script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub openit {
    my $path = shift;
    local *FH;
    return open (FH, $path) ? *FH : undef;
}

my $it = openit '</etc/fstab' or die "Can't open it: $!";
if (defined($_ = <$it>)) {
    print "Its first line is $_";
} else {
    print "It has no first line\n";
}
```

When the return value is `*FH`, the script works. When I change it to `\*FH`, the script fails. Because I'm using warnings, I see this:

```
readline() on unopened filehandle FH at scratch.pl line 11.
It has no first line
```

This happened because `\*FH` points to a global variable. In the sub, `local *FH` gave a temporary value to a global typeglob. When the sub returned, `*FH` lost its temporary value, and `FH` went back to being an unopened filehandle.

The fix is to copy the temporary value. This happens when the sub returns `*FH`. It copies the typeglob because it isn't an lvalue sub. Now I know why the sub must return `*FH`, not `\*FH`.

If I want the sub to return a reference, I can copy the typeglob and then take a reference:

```
local *FH;
return open (FH, $path) ? \(my $glob = *FH) : undef;
```

Or I can autovivify a reference:

```
my $globref;
return open ($globref, $path) ? $globref : undef;
```

If you change the value of `STDOUT` and you need to copy the old value, then you must copy the typeglob with `*STDOUT`, not `\*STDOUT`. You probably don't need to copy the value.