# Inline selection of FD as in docs does not work with strict refs

Tags: perl

In [the perldoc for `print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html), it says this should work:

```
print { $OK ? STDOUT : STDERR } "stuff\n";
```

But it does not with `use strict`, and when I then use quotes like

```
print { $OK ? "STDOUT" : "STDERR" } "stuff\n";
```

I get

```
Can't use string ("STDOUT") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use ...
```

How can I get this structure to work without doing away with `use strict`?

Comment: Try put a star in front of `STDOUT`, i.e. use a [typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles): `print { $OK ? *STDOUT : *STDERR } "stuff\n";`

Comment: Thank you, this solved it :) How am I supposed now to "close" the question?

Comment: See also [Why do I have to use a * in front of a Perl bareword filehandle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2242812/2173773)

Comment: Where in the docs did you find this? Please give us a link.

Comment: I did `perldoc -f print`. I found it on the web now at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html

Comment: I've submitted a patch to fix this - https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130880

Comment: This will be fixed in an upcoming version of Perl - https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/83cad6954f449afbbab19c7edd8045745aae6345

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
print { $OK ? *STDOUT : *STDERR } "stuff\n";
```

The asterisk means the typeglob. Since there is no sigils to denote a file handle, you have to use the typeglob sigil, the asterisk, instead.

Answer (score 5):

To prevent the error message `Bareword "STDOUT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ...` you'll have to use a typeglob:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $OK = 1 ;

printf { $OK ? *STDOUT : *STDERR } "stuff\n" ;
```